# AssertionError : List Differ in pytest django

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I created a simple test to test the API endpoint. However it kept returning `AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != [{'field_value': {'id': 1, 'panel_name': '[420 chars]: 2}]` and `Second list contains 4 additional elements. First extra element 0: {'field_value': {'id': 1, 'panel_name': 'Clinic A', 'panel_type': 1}, 'field_type': 'clinic', 'count': 3}`. Does anyone know why is this happening ? Does it means the expected content is not present inside the list ?

```
def test_api(self, query, expected):
        username = "jeff"
        password = "test"
        client = Client()

        response = client.post('/admin/login/', {'username': username, 'password': password})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

        balance_type_collection = [
            'medical',
            'dental'
        ]

        for balance_type in balance_type_collection:
            if query == '':
                query += '?'
            else:
                query += '&'

            query += 'balance_type=' + balance_type
            response = client.get('/api/v1/medical/clinicvisit/stats/'+ query)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            content = json.loads(response.content)
            self.assertEqual(content, expected[balance_type])
```

Comment: Either your expectation, your code or the server response is wrong. Hard to say without details.

Comment: `content` does not equal `expected[balance_type]`, so that assertion fails.

Comment: how do i solve this ? @JohnGordon

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix it, because we don't know what the code is _supposed_ to do.

Comment: Put ipdb debugger before the failing line, then you can check all variables that you want and see what is going on -  https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/